# Search AD with PowerShell without using AD module (RSAT)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

ActiveDirectory module comes with Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT). I would like to avoid the installation of RSAT on PC client. Is there a way to retrieve members of AD group without using Active Directory module?

Comment: Active Directory is actually just LDAP + Kerberos under the hood. You can use any standard LDAP tool to query the directory.

Comment: I need to use PowerShell for that (without any other additional libraries/modules).

Answer (score 12):

You could use `[ADSI]` to do an LDAP lookup:

```
$Group = [ADSI]"LDAP://CN=DistinguishedNameofGroup,DC=Example,DC=com"
$Group.Member
```

Alternatively you could use the [`DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$Search = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=group)(name=ExampleGroupName))")
$Results = $Search.FindAll()
$Results.Properties["Member"]

#As a one liner
([System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]"(&(objectCategory=group)(name=ExampleGroupName))").FindAll().Properties["Member"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem recently. I knew that the .Net Framework has everything for this! So I made a small [ADNAM](https://github.com/isKUL/NSPA/tree/main/ADNAM) PowerShell module, maybe it will be useful to someone.