# Get user's AD role without using Remote Server Administration Tools

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-10

I'm trying to write a powershell command that checks to see if a user is part of an AD Group, however, I don't want to use the RSAT modules, as this may end up being a logon script (and we don't want users having those modules installed). This did lead me to this question, [Search AD with PowerShell without using AD module (RSAT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000885/search-ad-with-powershell-without-using-ad-module-rsat), however, I can't figure out how to filter the results check it the value is in there.

For example, the below does return a list of users, in LDAP form, for the group `IT`, but how do I then check a specific user (with their Username, not display name) is in there?

```
([System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]"(&(objectCategory=group)(name=IT))").FindOne().Properties["Member"]
```

`FindOne()` despite what it says as well, returns multiple rows; in fact `FindAll()` and `FindOne()` both return the same results.

Should I be using a different command to search AD? Specifically I want to either check an AD group contains a user (the current user), or the inverse, check a user (the current user) is a member of a particular AD group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it that way if you really need to (and I can help you do it that way if you really need) but if you are going to be running this script under the credentials of the user you are interested in, then you can get all the groups from the user's login token. That already contains a recursive list of all security groups that the user is in. (It won't include groups where the 'Group type' is "Distribution")

The login token contains a list of SIDs, so the absolute fastest way is to compare using the SID of the group you are interested in, since it won't have to make any network request at all. That's especially convenient for laptop users who may not be online when they login - your script would still work.

```bsh
$currentIdentity = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()

if ($currentIdentity.Groups.Where({$_.Value -eq "S-1-1-0"}, "First")) { #Is in "Everyone"?
    "Yes"
} else {
    "No"
}
```

To find the SID of a group, use this:

```bsh
(Get-ADGroup "GroupName").SID.Value
```

Then copy/paste that value into the script.

If you would prefer to use the name of the group in the script, then you can convert it to a `WindowsPrincipal` and use [`IsInRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole). However, this will need to make a network request to find the group by its name.

```bsh
$currentIdentity = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$currentPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($currentIdentity)

if ($currentPrincipal.IsInRole("Everyone")) {
    "Yes"
} else {
    "No"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel; I was happy with "any" method, in truth it didn't necessarily need to be using what i had above (just what I'd managed to find from searching). This appears to work just as I need. Many thanks.